# Compiling RPL border router on Contiki

Tags: contiki

I am getting the following errors when compiling rpl-border-router.c (contiki 3.0) application for the minimal-net and native platforms:

> ```
> make border-router.sky TARGET=sky 
> mkdir obj_sky
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [border-router.sky] Error 1
> rm obj_sky/slip-bridge.o border-router.co obj_sky/httpd-simple.o 
> obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o
> Process returned error code 2
> ```